About the efficiency of pytorch in Reranker model
I get an efficiency problem in Reranker model.**
Here is detail:
In inference of PyTorch model, I add time() to collect the time in self.tokenizer and self.model. The inference info like this:
token_len: 2048 ; all data num: 1000; batch: 4 ;number of batch: 1000/4=250. I run in GPU(A800), and I get run time in self.tokenizer is 29.99s, model inference is 4.39s, so total time is almost 34.4s.
When I debug the code, I found the part of .to(self.device) take almost all the time of self.tokenizer.
But when I annotation code scores = self.model(**inputs, return_dict=True).logits.view(-1, ).float() ,I found the time of self.tokenizer become 4.16s.
Here is my inference code,
    @torch.no_grad()
    def compute_score(self, sentence_pairs, batch_size: int = 256,
                      max_length: int = 512, normalize: bool = False):
        if self.num_gpus > 0:
            batch_size = batch_size * self.num_gpus

        assert isinstance(sentence_pairs, list)
        if isinstance(sentence_pairs[0], str):
            sentence_pairs = [sentence_pairs]
        start = time()

        token_times=[]
        model_times=[]
        all_scores = []
        for start_index in tqdm(range(0, len(sentence_pairs), batch_size), desc="Compute Scores",
                                disable=len(sentence_pairs) < 128):
            sentences_batch = sentence_pairs[start_index:start_index + batch_size]

            token_start = time()
            inputs = self.tokenizer(
                sentences_batch,
                padding=True,
                truncation=True,
                return_tensors='pt',
                max_length=max_length,
            ).to(self.device)
            token_end = time()

            scores = self.model(**inputs, return_dict=True).logits.view(-1, ).float()
            model_end_time = time()
            #all_scores.extend(scores.cpu().numpy().tolist())
            token_times.append(token_end - token_start)
            model_times.append(model_end_time - token_end)

        #if normalize:
        #    all_scores = [sigmoid(score) for score in all_scores]

        token_all_time = sum(token_times)
        model_all_time = sum(model_times)
        return "", start, token_all_time, model_all_time

and token_all_time is time of self.tokenizer,and model_all_time is time of model inference.
Here is the link of source code: https://github.com/FlagOpen/FlagEmbedding/blob/master/FlagEmbedding/flag_reranker.py
And Here is the detail of this problem: https://github.com/FlagOpen/FlagEmbedding/issues/988
Is there more cost time in self.tokenizer or more in model inference.
and why the time cost of self.tokenizer from 29.99s to 4.16s?
Does anybody know why does this happen ?

please do not post screencaps of code. post code as plain text. output also should be in plain text

Sorry, I just want to describe the problem in as much detail as possible

the details added by a screencap may be relevant sometimes but i don't think it's the case here, and it's way more efficient to be able to copy/paste your code

ok and thankyou. I re-edit my problem here
